# wpdb doesn't execute query using IN operator after binding the array to a placeholder

Tags: php, sql, mysql, wordpress

I have this query:

```
$post_query = "SELECT * 
FROM wpps_terms t
INNER JOIN wpps_term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id AND t.term_id IN ($placeholder)
WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'property-area' AND t.name LIKE '%s' ";
```

which use the `IN` operator, I bind the values like this:

```
$taxonomiesArr = [4, 8];

$filter = array_map(function($v) {
    return "'" . esc_sql($v) . "'";
}, $taxonomiesArr);
$filter = implode(',', $filter);

$placeholder = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($filter), '%s'));
```

I'm trying to bind the `taxonomiesArr` like that:

```
$like = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like('columbia') . '%';
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($post_query, $taxonomiesArr, $like));
```

the problem's that the query is never execute and `wpdb->print_error()` doesn't show anything. I'm sure that the query isn't executed 'cause if I look `wpdb->last_query` I get the previous query executed.

If I change the prepare as:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($post_query, 4, 8, $like));
```

the query is executed, but why I get this behavior? I can't pass the values manually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 2 lines of code are causing the problem:

```
$filter = implode(',', $filter);
$placeholder = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($filter), '%s'));
```

You are converting `$filter` to a string *before* using it in `count`- you are probably getting the following warning in your logs: "*Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in...*"

This means the `array_fill` function is not working and you're `$placeholder` string is wrong

**How to fix this:**

Either move the filter `implode` line belwo the code where you set up your `$placeholder`, or save the `count` of the array into a variable before you implode it and use it instead of count:

```
$taxonomiesArr = [4, 8];

$filter = array_map(function($v) {
    return "'" . esc_sql($v) . "'";
}, $taxonomiesArr);

/* MOVE THIS LINE (or save count($filter) into a var before it)
   - it converts the array to string but you need an array for count in array_fill */
// $filter = implode(',', $filter);

$placeholder = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($filter), '%s'));

$filter = implode(',', $filter);
```

If you `print_r($placeholder);` at the end of the code above, you get `%s,%s` as expected